# Many to many doesn't persist

Tags: symfony-3.3

I'm developing a website with the PHP framework Symfony 3.3 and the ORM Doctrine.

I have users, and each user can offer services. A service can be offers by more than one user.

Everything is working well, except when I want to persist a services list of a user. Nothing happens and I don't get any error. Can you see anything that is wrong in my code?

My MySQL user table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
`id_user` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`firstname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`surname` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`address` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`zip` VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL,
`city` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`phone_number` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`mobile_number` VARCHAR(12) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`email` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`birth_date` DATE NOT NULL,
`is_verified` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`id_gender` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_user`),
UNIQUE INDEX `e-mail_UNIQUE` (`email`),
UNIQUE INDEX `id_utilisateur_UNIQUE` (`id_user`),
INDEX `fk_id_gender_idx` (`id_gender`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_id_gender` FOREIGN KEY (`id_gender`) REFERENCES `gender`         (`id_gender`)
)
```

My MySQL service_offer table:

```
CREATE TABLE `service_offer` (
`id_service_offer` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`id_user` INT(11) NOT NULL,
`id_service` INT(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_service_offer`),
UNIQUE INDEX `id_user_UNIQUE` (`id_user`),
INDEX `fk_service_idx` (`id_service`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_service` FOREIGN KEY (`id_service`) REFERENCES `service` (`id_service`),
CONSTRAINT `fk_user` FOREIGN KEY (`id_user`) REFERENCES `user` (`id_user`)
)
```

My MySQL service table:

```
CREATE TABLE `service` (
`id_service` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
`description` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id_service`),
UNIQUE INDEX `id_service_UNIQUE` (`id_service`)
)
```

A part of my user entity:

```
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_user", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $idUser;

/**
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Service")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="service_offer",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id_user")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_service", referencedColumnName="id_service")}
 *      )
 */
private $services;

function getServices() {
    return $this->services;
}

function setServices($services) {
    $this->services = $services;
    return $this;
}
```

My Service entity class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Service
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="service", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="id_service_UNIQUE", columns={"id_service"})}, indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_user_idx", columns={"user"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Service
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 */
private $description;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_service", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $idService;



/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Service
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set description
 *
 * @param string $description
 *
 * @return Service
 */
public function setDescription($description)
{
    $this->description = $description;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get description
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescription()
{
    return $this->description;
}

/**
 * Get idService
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getIdService()
{
    return $this->idService;
}
}
```

And if I'm doing that in a controller, nothing is persisting in the database:

```
$user->setServices($services);

$em->persist($user);
$em->flush();
```

This code:

```
print_r($services);
```

returns

```
Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection Object ( [elements:Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection:private] => Array ( [0] => AppBundle\Entity\Service Object ( [name:AppBundle\Entity\Service:private] => sdfgsdf [description:AppBundle\Entity\Service:private] => sdfgsdf [idService:AppBundle\Entity\Service:private] => 2 ) ) )
```

And this code:

```
echo $services[0]->getName();
```

returns this:

```
sdfgsdf
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found what was the problem!!! :) :)

I had XML files in my "\src\AppBundle\Resources\config\doctrine" folder because I generated my entity classes from an existing database. But the Many to many join wasn't generated automatically, so I had to add it manually.

Everytime I launched this command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

I had the information that everything was up to date. But actually, Symfony used the information stored in the XML files and not in the annotations....

So, I deleted the XML files, updated my schema again and now it's working. I saw that Symfony updated the table service_offer and deleted the column "id_service_offer" which is actually not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try persisting the services as well? For example:

```
$user->setServices($services);

$em->persist($user);
$em->persist($services);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: Thnaks for your reply. I get that error message: The class 'Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection' was not found in the chain configured namespaces AppBundle\Entity. And I think it's normal. We cannot persist an ArrayCollection. Or?

Comment: You may need to include a `use` statement at the top of your PHP file to import ArrayCollection. Try putting this line at the top of your file: `use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;`. Also see this for more info about PHP namespaces and importing: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: Have it already in my User class. Added it in the controller, but still the same error. But can we persist an array??

Comment: You can persist an ArrayCollection. I believe that the ArrayCollection object is actually defined in a Doctrine. You cannot, however, persist a pure array. If you're dealing with a standard PHP array, you can convert it to an ArrayCollection with `$servicesCollection = new ArrayCollection($services)`.